# Decorating a Bean with both Lombok and Spring annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Given the following classes in the same package:

CarOne:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CarOne {

    private String name;

    public CarOne() {
        System.out.println("Car One instantiated");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name = "Toyota";
    }
}
```

CarTwo:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    @Data
    public class CarTwo {

        public CarTwo() {
            System.out.println("Car Two instantiated");
        }

        private String name = "Ford";

    }
```

And the following test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class CarTest {

    @Autowired
    private CarOne carOne;

    @Autowired
    private CarTwo carTwo;

    @Test
    void getCarOneName(){
        System.out.println(carOne.getName());
    }

    @Test
    void getCarTwoName(){
        System.out.println(carTwo.getName());
    }
}
```

...the second test throws a compilation error in IntelliJ: `java: cannot find symbol, symbol: method getName()`

I am just starting out learning Spring Boot.  I have lots of classes where I'm using Lombok who's data I want to wire up using Spring Boot - it's probably obvious, but where am I going wrong?

Comment: check, whether your project builds without intellij. If so, it is an intellij issue.. you might have to enable lombok plugin and perhaps explicitly check annotation processing

Comment: can you show build.gradle ? and make sure you have enabled lombok in inteliji

Comment: thank you both, annotation processors was not enabled!